# Hibernate One To One Mapping , how not to insert child but bind to it

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Does someone knows a method to use a One To One Mapping where you save the parent but not inserting any children. Maybe the children already exist so I need to create a NEW Parent and just update an existing CHILD table row (with the new PARENT ID as FK).

Thanks !

Comment: @Manor i have updated the answer based on the additional info provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition a One To One means that there exists a one to one relationship between the two entities and therefore its not recommended to have one of the pair of objects lying around as an `orphan` when the other is deleted. Here is the official [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/) for the same.

Having said that, one of the quirks with JPA/hibernate is that by default JPA [OneToOne](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) (or even [OneToMany](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) for that matter) have its `orphanRemoval` field default to `false`. This means that if one were to use the annotations without specifying this and use the defaults then that will result in orphaned entities.

I am not sure if the above quirk is what is causing your need to update existing 'CHILD' that is associated with a different 'PARENT' in a One To One relationship. If so, please go ahead & specify it, `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)` and that will solve your problem.

If that is not the case and you would specifically like to NOT delete the 'CHILD' when you delete the 'PARENT' then i am not sure if One To One is the relationship mapping that should be used here. You can simply use a `@ManyToOne` with defaults and it will work.

---

OK, based on your additional clarifying comment for my query i see that there is no parent-child relationship between the entities involved. Rather, the requirement here seems to be that of a One-to-one with *Optional* relationship between the entities.

This can then be modeled in two ways,

- One is to specify the optional nature of the relationship (nullable foreign key) along with the appropriate cascading in the `OneToOne` declaration like this, `@OneToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})`.
- Two is to avoid putting null values in the fk column to handle optional relationship by modeling the relationship with a join table (just like how we would do for a many-to-many relationship),

Like below snippet,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
 
    //...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "car_parking", 
      joinColumns = 
        { @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
      inverseJoinColumns = 
        { @JoinColumn(name = "parkinglot_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private ParkingLot parkingLot;
 
    //... getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "parkinglot")
public class ParkingLot {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
 
    //...
 
    //... getters and setters
}
```

The preference of one over the other might depend on how frequently we would we have nulls..

Hope that answers..

:

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lmk ! Well yes, this is a strange situation/case. My CHILD table exsits way before any row on PARENT side. It is like a parking lot with fixed and limited amount of spots (rows in my case). So once in a while a new Car (PARENT in my case) comes in and sets the spot as occupied by that new Car (PARENT row). So O don't ever need to delete any CHILD rows, just update the column that indicates which Parent it is associated to (null if the new Car leaves the parking lot). Maybe this way is clearer :)

Comment: @Mainor thanks for the additional clarification of the req....i have updated the answer accordingly..hope that answers..cheers!

Comment: @Mainor Did that answer or help you?

Comment: YES @Imk........